# Trying to get nested Information but returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get the following information for info by doing the following

```
 for (let productKey in SearchResult) {
          if (SearchResult.hasOwnProperty(productKey)) {
            products.push({
              name: SearchResult[productKey]['info']['name'],
              image: SearchResult[productKey]['info']['image'],
              url_key: SearchResult[productKey]['info']['url_key'],
              productId: SearchResult[productKey]['info']['pid'],
            });
```

The result looks like this on console

[image: console image]

however I keep getting an error that says undefined.

would really like some help here as i have been stuck for quite a bit

I believe the error is name is undefined but in the console under info there is a name.

Comment: Please include the exact error message in the question and ideally some data that reproduces the issue. There's a good chance one of your search results doesn't have one of the properties you are attempting to read.

Comment: @dbs "Cannot read property 'info' of undefined" is the exact one

Comment: @dbs also the screenshot shows the data so it is there, i think its just a matter of getting to the nested information. if I do SearchResult[0] itll give me 93493 like in the screenshot but anything after i cant figure out how to get

Comment: You're not deep enough. Your array comes back as an Array with ten elements, each one with an unknown number of objects inside it. So technically, if you want to do the first "page", ` for (let productKey in SearchResult[0]) {` though you might want to iterate over `SearchResult` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `of` keyword to avoid the lookup and add a check for the `info` property:

```js
for (const product of SearchResult) 
    if(product.info)
        products.push({
            name: product.info.name,
            image: product.info.image,
            url_key: product.info.url_key,
            productId: product.info.pid
        });
```

I can see that the first `product.info` is populated from your screenshot, but your script needs every `product.info` to be populated to run.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much, can you explain why this works a little better as to what i did wrong.

Comment: @godhelpmeimstuck12 try putting a breakpoint on `if(product.info)` and seeing when it's undefined, that's probably your cause.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, it looks like your code doesn't match the structure of your data.

In this loop, you will start with the first key in searchResult: 0. searchResult[0] has a property 93493, but no property 'info'. Thus, when you try to get sub-properties out of it, you can't, because searchResult[0]['info'] is undefined. There is a searchResult[0][93493]['info'], but that's not what you're telling it to return.

You need to wrap this in another loop:

```js
for (let idx in SearchResult) {
    if (SearchResult.hasOwnProperty(idx)) {
        for (let propertyKey in SearchResult[idx]) {
            products.push({
              name: SearchResult[idx][productKey]['info']['name'],
              image: SearchResult[idx][productKey]['info']['image'],
              url_key: SearchResult[idx][productKey]['info']['url_key'],
              productId: SearchResult[idx][productKey]['info']['pid'],
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: would you be able to type out how it would look?